# Is a site still using my name server?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003

I've got an old DNS server running Server 2003 with ~150 forward lookup zones. I need to find out which of these sites are no longer using my DNS server as their name server. I know I could whois each of them individually, but I was hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: You could pop wireshark on and watch for traffic

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a DNS recursive query for each of them, starting from root-servers (this recursive query is called a DNS traversal) and see if the NS records point to your server. Can be easily scripted with dig or nslookup and a loop that goes through your list.

Comment: +1 to what Florin said - I used this online tool in the past http://dns.squish.net/